# the JVM memory is different from the system monitor ps -aux \ top and so on

Tags: jvm

I have set the properties Xmx 160M and nonheap memory 168M for the jvm process.
Here is the output I get by arthas.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 MEMORY                                                                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HEAP-MEMORY-USAGE                 init : 134217728(128.0 MiB)                                                        
 [memory in bytes]                 used : 76072912(72.5 MiB)                                                          
                                   committed : 152109056(145.1 MiB)                                                   
                                   max : 162201600(154.7 MiB)                                                         
 NO-HEAP-MEMORY-USAGE              init : 20971520(20.0 MiB)                                                          
 [memory in bytes]                 used : 141588040(135.0 MiB)                                                        
                                   committed : 157024256(149.8 MiB)                                                   
                                   max : 176160768(168.0 MiB)                                                         
 PENDING-FINALIZE-COUNT            0                                                                                  
                                                                                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 OPERATING-SYSTEM                                                                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 OS                                Linux                                                                              
 ARCH                              amd64                                                                              
 PROCESSORS-COUNT                  2                                                                                  
 LOAD-AVERAGE                      20.19                                                                              
 VERSION                           5.10.0-60.18.0.50.h1002.eulerosv2r11.x86_64                                        
                                                                                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 THREAD                                                                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 COUNT                             89                                                                                 
 DAEMON-COUNT                      52                                                                                 
 PEAK-COUNT                        89                                                                                 
 STARTED-COUNT                     233                                                                                
 DEADLOCK-COUNT                    0
```

But I found that the rss is 512M.

Anyone know the reason?